# Java app and grep - how can I independently process command output passed to grep with two regexs?

Tags: regex, shell, text, grep, pipe

I have a Java application using a SSH connection, remotely running CLI commands.  For a specific command, I would like to pipe the command's output through two regular expressions, finding two correlated subsets of the overall output and return that output back to my program.

For each of the two regular expressions: <**RE1**> & <**RE2**>, I would like to format the resulting outputs: <**RE1out**> & <**RE2out**> via <**action1**> & <**action2**> respectively; then return the final result, for example (please excuse the pseudo shell-script):

```
<command> | grep -e <RE1> -e <RE2> | (<REout1> given to <action1> and <REout2> given to   <action2>) yields <final_output>
```

Comment: You’re actually going to call **another program** from Java? Isn’t that sort of heretical?  “Java is the way, and the truth, and the light, and no man cometh unto his data save through Java.”

Comment: I'm not sure how you draw that conclusion... actually, I'm not even sure this question should have been tagged with Java in the first place... :)

Comment: do you want the output from both actions to be returned to your main program, or do you really mean the output from the command is to be returned?

Comment: @glenn jackman I Updated the original question to reflect the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use this process which temporarily creates a couple of temp files, but is still a one-liner:

```
command | 
awk '/RE1/ {print >> "tmp1"} /RE2/ {print >> "tmp2"}' && 
{ action1 < tmp1; action2 < tmp2; rm tmp1 tmp2; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<command> | tee >(grep -e <RE1> | <action1>) >(grep -e <RE2> | <action2>)
```